# Windows Security Center Service is missing

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-registry, windows-services

I am trying to fix a Windows 7 machine here that has been infected with all kinds of Malware. I have removed all of them as far as I can see but I am stumped by one last task.

One little bugger managed to remove the Windows Security Center service from the list of Windows services. So I cannot start it or set to automatically start. At the moment I cannot get the Windows firewall to turn on or any anti-virus software.

The security center shows the following image when I try:

[image: 1]

Does anyone know how to add this back to the list of services so I may set it to start. I don't have a backup of the registry for this computer (it's not mine).

Many thanks

TT

Comment: I would run the sfc integrity check.  Of course the far easier option is to nuke the system because it cannot be trusted at this point.

Comment: If it were me I'd format the drive and start again. Far quicker in the long term and the plus side is you'll have a clean system too.

Answer (score 0):

Service can be created like this:

1. Run cmd.exe as `Administrator`
2. exec this command:
   `sc create wscsvc binpath= "C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted" type= share start= delayed-auto error= normal depend= RpcSs/Winmgmt obj= "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" DisplayName= "Windows Security Center"`
3. and exec this also:
   `sc sdset wscsvc D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CR;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRP;;;S-1-5-80-2006800713-1441093265-249754844-3404434343-1444102779)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)`

Don't know if this will work properly, but you'll have your service :)